# AnyChartView has getting a memory leak when activity destroyed

Tags: android, memory-leaks, anychart, leakcanary

I am using LeakCanary for detecting memory leak and I am new to it. When my activity destroyed it was giving me a report of leaking. I am also not familiar on anychart library. How can I address this issue? Below is my codes of the activity and the stacktrace of the leakcanary. Also if possible can you please elaborate to me on how to read the stacktrace of leakcanary.

```
public class AnalyticsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_analytics);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        AnyChartView anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);
        anyChartView.setProgressBar(findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));

        Cartesian cartesian = AnyChart.column();

        List<DataEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Rouge", 80540));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Foundation", 94190));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Mascara", 102610));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Lip gloss", 110430));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Lipstick", 128000));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Nail polish", 143760));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Eyebrow pencil", 170670));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Eyeliner", 213210));
        data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Eyeshadows", 249980));

        Column column = cartesian.column(data);

        column.tooltip()
                .titleFormat("{%X}")
                .position(Position.CENTER_BOTTOM)
                .anchor(Anchor.CENTER_BOTTOM)
                .offsetX(0d)
                .offsetY(5d)
                .format("${%Value}{groupsSeparator: }");

        cartesian.animation(true);
        cartesian.title("Top 10 Cosmetic Products by Revenue");

        cartesian.yScale().minimum(0d);

        cartesian.yAxis(0).labels().format("${%Value}{groupsSeparator: }");

        cartesian.tooltip().positionMode(TooltipPositionMode.POINT);
        cartesian.interactivity().hoverMode(HoverMode.BY_X);

        cartesian.xAxis(0).title("Product");
        cartesian.yAxis(0).title("Revenue");

        anyChartView.setChart(cartesian);
    }
}
```

```
┬───
    │ GC Root: System class
    │
    ├─ com.anychart.APIlib class
    │    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
    │    ↓ static APIlib.instance
    │                    ~~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.anychart.APIlib instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ APIlib.anyChartView
    │             ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.anychart.AnyChartView instance
    │    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
    │    mContext instance of com.dreamakers.clustore.clustorestore.Activity.AnalyticsActivity with mDestroyed = true
    │    View#mParent is set
    │    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    │    View.mID = R.id.any_chart_view
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    ↓ AnyChartView.mContext
    ╰→ com.dreamakers.clustore.clustorestore.Activity.AnalyticsActivity instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.dreamakers.clustore.clustorestore.Activity.AnalyticsActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
    ​     key = 7ac56641-d049-41a3-8cb8-0a2cae7cc320
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 8099
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 3098
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AnyChart-Android library has a memory leak. I filed an issue here: https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/190

Until that's fixed, you can work around it that way:

```java
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    APIlib.setActiveAnyChartView(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easies thing you can do I think is to assign AnyChartView to global variable, and then in `onDestroy()` method of the activity just assign null to it:

```java
public void onDestroy() {
    anyChartView = null;
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

The case here is that AnyChartView is holding a reference to the Context of the Activity, and that's why the Activity cannot be easily garbage collected because of the way the library is storing this reference.

Comment: Hello! I tried to do that but it doesn't working. I am still getting the same error.